# MySQL SELECT LIKE query, ignoring colour codes in strings

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a database of strings containing names mixed with and colour codes (such as §2, §6, §a), for example.

```
§2joe (joe)
```

However some colour codes are mixed in the word, for example.

```
§4ha§6rr§ay (harry)
```

Lets say I want to select everyone from the database with a name of Harry, regardless of their colour codes.

My current solution is to add % to each letter of the search. For example.

```
SELECT * FROM people WHERE name LIKE '%h%a%r%r%y%';
```

This works for names that start with a colour code, but does not seem to always work with names mixed with colour codes.

Is there a better way for me to do the query?

Comment: I think the wildcards aren't working all the time is because of the color code §a and others with letters in them. A name with an 'a' and a color code §a could have a problem... can you change the color codes to all numbers?

Comment: The codes are set, can't change those.

Answer (score 2):

There is probably a better way to store the data.

Split the formatting from the actual data (save two fields).  For example. on insert save a "clean" version of the data, along with a 
"formatted" version.

There's no reason the wild cards shouldn't work, but they will match more than just "harry."  They will also be much slower.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM people WHERE REPLACE(name,'§a','') LIKE '%h%a%r%r%y%';
```

Taking out problem color codes may get what you want. That is if you don't have a color code for every letter of the alphabet